# bootstrap vue radio button

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, radio-button, bootstrap-vue

I would like to 1) make sure radio buttons are aligned to left 2) decrease the amount of vertical space between label and radio button texts and vertical space between each text

In the example below you can see radio button texts are centered, and also there is about half text height space between them which I would like to decrease

https://codesandbox.io/s/1l3yc9?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the previous answer to fully answer your question, the label of the radio button can be left aligned using bootstrap's flex class names:

```
<b-form-radio
        v-model="orderType"
        :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
        name="radios-stacked"
        value="L"
        class="d-flex justify-content-start"
        >Limit</b-form-radio
      >
```

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-worker-5hozrv) to completely working CodeSandbox

Comment: excellent, can you point out how you found the answer to this; I need to learn to find my way for similar issues on other bootstrap vue components.

Comment: I inspected the label and noticed the inner text was center aligned, [like so](https://i.imgur.com/Xd0GqI7.png).  I first tried adding `text-align: left` but that didn't work. Then I noticed the label was styled with flex and `justify-content: center` seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/p8Aulx8.png).  Changing it to `justify-content: start` left aligns the text inside the label. Could've added this CSS inside the component <style> tags to override but I'm familiar enough with bootstrap to know it provides utility classnames to do the same thing, hence the 'd-flex justify-content-start' classes

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

1. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain please?
2. Add the following CSS:

Reduce the vertical space between the label and the first radio button:

```
legend#__BVID__6__BV_label_,
legend#__BVID__12__BV_label_ {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Reduce the vertical space between the two radio buttons:

```
.custom-control {
  min-height: initial;
}

.custom-control-label {
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-label::after {
  top: 1px;
}
```

See the forked CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-microservice-pc7y33?file=/App.vue).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the radio buttons from getting centered, remove the class `class="form-inline"` from your `<b-form-group></b-form-group>`.

It will adjust the texts accordingly.

So you should have something like this:

```js
  <b-form-group
    label="Order type"
    v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }"
    label-align="left"
  >
    ...
  </b-form-group>
```